# CreateService in 64-bit architecture

Tags: c++, winapi, service, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Primary acceptable values for the *dwServiceType* parameter of the **[CreateService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** WinAPI's function are **`SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS`** and **`SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS`**.
As for the appearing of "WIN32", are those values fit also in 64-bit a software?

And, generally, is the routine of creating services different between 32- and 64-bit architectures (in C++, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "WIN32" applies to the name of the *api layer*, it doesn't have anything to do with the bitness of the process.  Win32 was the successor to the 16-bit api used in Windows 3.x, one of the three sub-systems supported on NT (Posix and OS/2 are the forgotten ones).

Clearly it is a source of confusion after the winapi got ported to 64-bit, the reason that the [win32] tag on SO now redirects to [winapi].

And no, creating 64-bit services isn't different.  Just add the "x64" Platform target on your project and recompile.  As long as you wrote clean code, this works without having to make any changes at all.  YMMV.