# How to run 64bit c++ console exe as a service in windwos service

Tags: c++, windows-services, visual-studio-2019, syswow64

i am trying to run a c++ console app as a service in windows but i have build the exe in 64 bit config in VS2019. I can able to install and remove the service but if i start the service its shows following status in CMD

> ```
>     TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
> ```

```
    STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                            (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
    CHECKPOINT         : 0x1
    WAIT_HINT          : 0x258
    PID                : 23248
```

is it possible to change the Service type to WINX64 process or is there any sample i have used git hub SampleService code to create a service app out of console c++ app.Following is the service creation called in my sample

```
        hService = CreateService(
        hManager,                   // SCManager database
        _T("SampleService"),                 // name of service
        _T("SampleService app"), // name to display
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,         // desired access
        SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS | // service type
        SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS,
        SERVICE_AUTO_START,         // start type
        SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,       // error control type
        Target,                     // service's binary
        NULL,                       // no load ordering group
        NULL,                       // no tag identifier
        NULL,                       // dependencies
        NULL,                       // LocalSystem account
        NULL);                      // no password
```

i am trying to run as a syswow64 kind of app

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? Here is a similar thread:[CreateService in 64-bit architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731075/createservice-in-64-bit-architecture)

Comment: yes but i can't able to start service its failing on CreateService to get pointer and load hService value it throws 1063 error code in win11

Answer (score 0):

WIN32_OWN_PROCESS doesn't mean 32 bit. You can check the service bit through task manager->Details.